# SPServices - GetGroupCollectionFromUser - Limit Scope to Current SP Site

Tags: spservices

I'm currently using SPServices `GetGroupCollectionFromUser` to return all the Groups an SP user belongs to and it is working awesome!

Would like to know if there is a way to limit the scope of `GetGroupCollectionFromUser` to return only the Groups the user is in associated to the current SP Site vs. returning all the groups a user is in?

SPServices-0.7.2.js
SharePoint 2010 Foundation
IE9

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the webURL: option in you SPServices Call?  Try adding that and put your sitecollection URL into this and see if it works. (Taken from the SPServices Documentation)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  webURL:"Your Site Collection Address"
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='GroupName']").length == 1) {
      $("#zz9_ID_PersonalizePage").remove();
      /*   zz5_ID_LoginAsDifferentUser
           zz6_ID_RequestAccess
           zz7_ID_Logout
           zz8_MSOMenu_ChangePassword
           zz9_ID_PersonalizePage   */
    }
  }
}); /*close().SPServices({ */
}); /* close (document).ready(function() { */
```